# When I add a position: absolute to my navbar, the justify-content: space-between stops working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a header image with a navbar that is floating on top of it.

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H6Mz.png)

That is with the css and html as

```
<div class="header-container">

<!-- START HEADER IMAGE -->
<section class="header-image">
  <img src="./img/cntower.png">
</section>

<!-- END HEADER IMAGE -->

<!-- TOP LEVEL NAVIGATION -->
<div class="navbar">
  <div>
    <p>
      <strong>GTA Wholesale</strong>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><strong>All</strong></p>
    <p><a>Published</a></p>
    <p><a>Drafts</a></p>
    <p><a>Deleted</a></p>
    <p><a>New</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- END TOP LEVEL NAVIGATION -->


</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width 100%;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 0;
}

.header-image {
  display: flex;
}

.header-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

On my navbar class, if I remove the position: absolute it doesn't go ontop of my image but when there is a position absolute the space-between attribute doesn't apply. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave `absolute` parameter and add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to your `navbar` class.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cg4pwod8/